# Sending a 37 K file with HTTP

Tags: java, objective-c, http

I am writing a program (in Objective C) to send a file of size 37 K across the Internet. I have written another program (in Java) to receive it that should run on the server. The trouble is, when the file arrives, the server program only receives a small part of it, not the entire file. Is the 37 K file being broken into smaller components?

```
 public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        // Respond to input
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " +
                this.serverText + " - " +
                time +
                "").getBytes());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String now = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        mw.print("Date and time: " + now);


        // read input
        int num_bytes = input.available();
        mw.print("Number of bytes received: " + num_bytes);
        byte [] info = new byte[num_bytes];
        for (int i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++)
        {
            info[i] = (byte) input.read();
        }

        // s contains all the info that we need

        analyse_input(info, num_bytes);

        output.close();
        input.close();      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // report exception
        mw.print("Problem receiving incoming file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code on both ends. The HTTP request will be broken into packets, yes. Chances are you're just calling `read()` a single time on an `InputStream` and assuming it'll read the whole data - but we can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: Perhaps. Or perhaps not. You will have to add some of your code to the question for us to help you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input.available() might not give you total number of bytes which are in the stream.
rather use the following code

```
byte [] info = new byte[1024];
while(input.read(info)!=-1){
 //write logic to append your bytes here
}
analyse_input(/*Your array with appended bytes*/, num_bytes);
```

Comment: indeed, input.available returns the number of byte available without having to do a blocking call on the stream.

Comment: Thanks very much. The code works a lot better now.

Comment: @Fred Smith Fred, if you feel this is the correct answer then can you please mark it as an "accepted" answer.:)

Comment: I am having a few problems again. Sometimes only part of a JPEG file arrives. Do I have to receive several parts separately, and then attach them together?